# 100% connreset with httperf?

Tags: load-testing, httperf

I'm wondering what the importance of the connreset with httperf is. When testing a single webpage, I receive no errors. When using a simple .log file with several pages, I am getting 100% connreset errors. Suggestions on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up having to track this down as I ran into it myself. The man page says the following:

```
connreset: The number of times a TCP connection failed due to a RESET from the
server. Typically, a RESET is received when the client attempts to send data to
the server at a time the server has already closed its end of the connection.
NT servers also send RESETs when attempting to establish a new connection when
the listen queue is full.
```

To get my own server implementation to stop doing this I had to disable the server side connection closing. It turned out that the server was being too aggressive about closing the connection.